# Why is this question marked as "too broad"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, too-broad

Recently, I asked a question named [What would happen if somebody knew how to make the Asterix's & Obelix's magic potion work nowadays?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/55640/what-would-happen-if-somebody-knew-how-to-make-the-asterixs-obelixs-magic-po). It was too broad, because it was asking for

> What would happen if somebody nowadays knew how to brew it?

And, of course, it got 3 close votes (it was indeed too broad). So I edited; after a few edits I got to

> What are the most important global economic, politic and safety changes that would happen if somebody nowadays knew how to make it?

But still, it got closed. @Philipp left a comment that "*When you pick one of these I might retract my close-vote*" I edited again and narrowed the question *even more*; The question now asked this:

> What are the most important global economic changes that would happen if somebody nowadays knew how to make it?

**Edit:** I edited again; Now it's

> What global economic changes would happen if somebody nowadays knew how to make it?

And this **isn't too broad** for sure. Was the last version (2nd quote) OK - should I edit it back - or should I leave it like this?

**Can the post be reopened now please?**

Answer (score 4):

One possibility is that you are approaching this from the wrong angle. The trouble is you don't have a specific outcome in mind. You're asking "when I do this, what happens". If instead you ask "I have this starting point, I'm trying to get to this end point, how do I do it?" then it is much easier to have that question suitably constrained.

Asking questions along the first lines is possible within the scope of the site, but it is *much* harder. See if you can reformat it into the second form and you will find it much easier.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I think you went from "too broad", to "primarily opinion-based". And it is still quite broad, we would need to consider all the possible consequences, and then pick "the most" out of them.

Generally any question about "the most", "the best", etc. if they aren't followed by a measurable quantity, they make the question unanswerable. How are we to judge what is "important" and what isn't? If we can't judge, we can't vote, and if we can't vote, we can't answer.

Comment: So I should edit... what about `What are some global economic changes that would happen if somebody nowadays knew how to make it?` Or perhaps something else?